# WP JSON API Angular.js user login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, api, cookies

I'm struggling to log in a user correctly via the WP REST API (http://wp-api.org/) using angular. I have it working so far by using basic auth when requesting the wordpress users via /users - but this doesn't seem like best practice, and it doesn't provide cookies in the response.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the documentation for WP REST API, I'm not seeing that it provides any kind of cookie login feature.

There is, however, a plugin for this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-auth/

Passing back a cookie via a secured JSON call is totally normal. Usually it's just passed with the Set-Cookie header, and your browser automatically knows what to do with it.

If you want to get really fancy and drop cookies all together, check out [JWT](https://github.com/psignoret/aad-sso-wordpress/blob/master/JWT.php) = ) New stateless way for doing auth. You'll need to do somewhat fancy WP coding, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had seen that around, but it's for the alternative version of the API. Just added it and it seems to be working ok so far.